# Least lossy file conversion for PDF

Tags: pdf, documents, docx, rtf

I need to convert a whole bunch of PDFs to some other file format (Doc, DocX, RTF etc), and then back to a PDF a little later.

I need to the new PDFs to look the same as far as possible.

Is there any difference between these file formats as to how lossy the conversion will be, or does it not really matter? What factors will make a difference?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask): "Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDF is a *page layout description* format: It describes the general structure of the document, resources like fonts and embedded images, a tree of all pages, and possible other things. For each page, it contains commands to put certain glyphs into certain positions, or other image operations, like placing an embedded image.

The other three formats you mention (Doc, DocX, RTF) are Microsoft-specific "source" formats, which describes sequences of characters with attributes, and doesn't describe (at least in principle) the layout of these characters on visible pages.

So all conversion from PDF into any of these formats (and basically all formats you can sensibly edit) will be lossy. **Very** lossy.

If you put enough effort in the conversion, you may get an PDF back that resembles more or less the original PDF, but making it look the same is really, **really** difficult.

Bottom line: PDFs are not editable. Edit whatever was used to create the PDF. If you don't have access to that, tough luck. You can still try to edit the PDF directly, but that's also not easy.